# Desktop problem with 3 screens

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, video

I have a notebook that has 2 video cards, and I'm using 3 screens. Two screens are using the first video card (Intel graphics 4000), but this video card support only 2 screens, then i have to use the another one (NVIDIA NVS5200M) to the third screen, but it gave me a visual bug:

Normal Screen
[image: .]

Bugged screen
[image: .]

Note that in the bugged screen, the pointer appears correctly, so i presume that is the desktop is bugged, but I'm in certainty that is directly related with the second video card.